# Makefile trailing error "Command not found" when calling custom shell function

Tags: bash, git, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile:

```
       define git_all
            ls --recursive --directory --color=never */.git                         \
            | sed 's/\/.git//'                                                      \
            | xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-procs=10 --replace={} git -C '{}' $1 || true
       endef

       gitpull:
            @$(call git_all,pull -v)
```

The 'gitpull' rule is supposed to detect any and all repositories in the subfolders that are under the folder that the Makefile is in. For example:

```
    Makefile
    \- a/.git
    \- b/.git
    ...
```

When I run 'make gitpull' the scripts works fine with one minor glitch. If a repository is already up to date I get this weird trailing error:

```
   > make gitpull
   make: Already: Command not found
   make: *** [Makefile:xxx: gitpull] Error 127
```

I guess the shell is trying to interpret the text 'Already up to date' as a command and its failing. But why does it try to do that in the first place? I'm obviously missing something but what?

Comment: Generally [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thanks for the sidetip. Feel free to propose an safer alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what `$(shell ...)` does. If you want this to happen when the target is run, not when the Makefile is parsed, you want to take out the `$(shell ...)`.

Also, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

If I'm able to guess what you are trying to do, probably something like

```
define git-all
find . -type d -name '.git' -execdir sh -c 'cd ..; git -C $1' _ {} \;
endef

here:
    $(call git-all,pull -v)
```